# Misaligned titlebar icons in Google Chrome

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, titlebar, elementary, pantheon

I had installed Pantheon desktop on my Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 using the elementary os ppas. However, that messes up with the title bar in Google Chrome, as the snapshot shows. The problem persists even after removing Pantheon, uninstalling/reinstalling Chrome.

[image]

It would hep if we could fix the issue with the misaligned icons in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to fix the problem using the following settings:

In gconf-editor, go to apps-> metacity -> general and set the button_layout to something like "menu:minimize,maximize,close". This solves the problem.